# HQL compare existing Objects tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I just want to explain following scenario.

I have **Registration** table for employee

It has one field like BranchAddress, and I have using table **Branch** for that with **ManyToOne** mapping.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "temp_reg")
public class TemporaryRegistrationDTO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ID;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private BranchDTO companyBranch;
public BranchDTO getCompanyBranch() {
    return companyBranch;
}
public void setCompanyBranch(BranchDTO companyBranch) {
    this.companyBranch = companyBranch;
}
public int getID() {
    return ID;
}
public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_branch")
public class BranchDTO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int branchID;
public int getBranchID() {
    return branchID;
}
public void setBranchID(int branchID) {
    this.branchID = branchID;
}
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private CountriesDTO country;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private StatesDTO state;
public CountriesDTO getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(CountriesDTO country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public StatesDTO getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(StatesDTO state) {
    this.state = state;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_countries")
public class CountriesDTO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private String countryCode;
public String getCountryCode() {
    return countryCode;
}
public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
    this.countryCode = countryCode;
}

private String countryName;
public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}
public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_states")
public class StatesDTO {

@Id
@GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int state_id;
private String state;
private String stateCode;
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getStateCode() {
    return stateCode;
}
public void setStateCode(String stateCode) {
    this.stateCode = stateCode;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StatesDTO [statesID=" + state_id + ", state=" + state + ", stateCode=" + stateCode + "]";
}
public int getState_id() {
    return state_id;
}
public void setState_id(int state_id) {
    this.state_id = state_id;
}
```

}

Now, What I want is that, whenever their is request for registration, Firstly I am checking if Branch Address is available in the **Branch** table. If it contains an entry already, then it will retrieve Branch row and stooping from same  data to Branch Table

Now, to check for **BranchDTO**, I have created method in **Branch Repository** class.

```
@Query("from BranchDTO where country = :country and state = :state")
public BranchDTO existsEntry(@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param("country") CountriesDTO country,@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param("state") StatesDTO state);
```

But It reflects me following error,

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.example.demo.pojo.CountriesDTO
```

Thank you guys

Comment: You're not posting the code you're executing, and you're notpoting the stack trace of the exception. So it's very hard to help. Also, DTO means Data Transfer Object. Basically the inverse of what an entity is. A cascade ALL on a ManyToOne doesn't make sense. You don't want to delete a country when you delete one of the branches referring to that country.

Comment: @jay Vyas can you please upload the main code where you are creating the objects and saving those objects